# In Android Compose function, what's the best way to convert a nullable LiveData variable to Compose state?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

For a normal LiveData variable in the view model, eg

```
val data = MutableLiveData<City>()
```

We can observe it using

```
data.observeAsState()
```

My question is, say I have an optional LiveData variable like

```
var data: MutableLiveData<City>? = null
```

What would be the proper way to handle it in a composable function?

At the time, the best way I can see is to unwrap everything outside the composable function

```
group?.let {
  it.observe(this) { groupData ->
      Content(groupData)
  }
}?: run {
  Content(null)       
}


@Compasable
fun Content(group: Group?) {
  ...
}
```

Is there a more Compose-oriented way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can observe it from Composable function pretty much the same way you do it with NonNull `LiveData`, just using some kotlin null-safe operators:

```
val group: Group? = data?.observeAsState()?.value
```

I guess that most of your confusion comes from using the `by` property delegate, which doesn't really work (does more harm than good) for Nullable `LiveData`. Firstly, you will have to do something like the following example, which is not very nice, and then you won't be able to use Kotlin's smart cast because *"group is a property that has open or custom getter"*. However, using `.value` is equivalent to `by` delegation and in some cases better.

```
// this is nice
val group: Group by data.observeAsState()
// you can also do this, but don't
val group: Group? by (data?.observeAsState() ?: mutableStateOf(null))
```

Comment: You are right about the `by` part. That totally tripped me.